# How to perform integration testing using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, testing, integration-testing, jestjs

I am writing a Node.js application that acts as GraphQL server. And I want to test if GraphQL is giving me the right results.

My guess is to make a request to server in each test and then watch if it is right or not. But I'm not sure how to set it up, how to run the server and clean the database before all tests and shutting it down after all tests are finished.

I worked with `rspec` using `Ruby on Rails` before, so I want to do something like `rspec` does in Node.js. Is there a way to accomplish it using Jest? And if not, how can I do something simular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really an Jest specific question but more how to perform integration testing in Node.

The fact you're using Jest makes very little difference other than you'll want to ensure auto mocking is turned off.

Normally when writing integration style tests I'd use something like [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to make requests and setup the database to use sqlLite or similar running a seed.

I'd recommend looking for similar tools like [graphql-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tester).

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, this question is more about integration testing in Node.js. I've change the question title to represent it. And thanks for the answer!